# 2-Column Container 100% Body Height

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm using this example fyi: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/ (where the left column is a fixed width via px and the right is re-sizable)

I'm trying to make the height of the container 100% of the body height.

e.g. forget the bottom content (the copy code) on that page, just the top layout example, how would I make the height of that (no matter if there's content or not) 100% the body height. With content I'm trying to get it to scroll, without (if any) it needs to be 100% height of the body minimum.

Any suggestions, no luck so far..

My `jsfiddle` example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GtK98/1/

Comment: I'm trying to make the two columns 100% height (to match the body) even if there say is no content in the divs.

Comment: do you also want a footer? or just header and content?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
min-height:100%;
```

in the css?

Answer (score 0):

this is a layout without a footer, If you want to add a footer comment here and I'll do that to.

Pure CSS, without Fixing the header height, with/without fixing the left side width, cross browser (IE8+)

Take a look at that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/CTJwQ/)

**HTML:** (very basic)

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <div class="LeftContent">
            </div>
            <div class="RightContent">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.HeightTaker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .HeightTaker:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.Header
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.Wrapper > div
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.LeftContent
{
    float: left;

    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
.RightContent
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #77578a;
}
```